# Service as ASMX and WCF

Tags: wcf, asmx

I have an existing web service (ASMX) that needs to be exposed as WCF as well. ASMX must remain and preferably with no change on the client. As per [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2006/10/05/phased-migration-from-asmx-to-wcf.aspx) I have configured as follows. The service layer is generated with CodeSmith and whilst I didn't write these services I know they are fine as they have been used in the wild for many years. The names have been changed to protect the innocent .. grin.

In the service layer there is an `XXX.YYY.MyService` class generated by CodeSmith which is double decorated with

```
[ServiceContract( Namespace = "http://XXX.YYY" )]
```

and

```
[WebService( Namespace = "http://XXX.YYY", Name = "MyService" )]
```

I have also created an empty interface `XXX.YYY.IMyService` which is implemented by `MyService`. At this point I can consume the ASMX service with no issues.

Now I add a .svc file to the service layer which contains ...

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXX.YYY.MyService" %>
```

... and I configure the service layer's web.config with ...

```
<system.serviceModel>


  <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>


  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="XXX.YYY.MyService">
    <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="XXX.YYY.IMyService">
     <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
     </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
   </service>
  </services>


 </system.serviceModel>
```

If I build and then try and make a service reference in Visual Studio 2010 to the service, I see both .ASMX and .SVC versions of `MyService`. Expanding the .svc branch in the Add Service Reference dialog results in an error referring to an empty XML document.

If I examine the event log I get ...

> WebHost failed to process a request.
>    Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/39449526
>    Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/System/MyService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The contract name 'XXX.YYY.IMyService' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'MyService'.. --->

... but `MyService` is marked as implementing `IMyService` ...

```
public partial class MyService : IMyService
```

I have also tried changing the contract attribute for the service to `MyService` instead of the interface. That works but for the client code breaks as any attempt to create an instance of the service fails as it is now an interface.

I hope that makes sense. Please feel free to ask anything extra. I have tried to be as detailed as possible.

(No IIS involved .. this is purely in Visual Studio 2010).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for me was to move the [ServiceContract] and [OperationContract] declarations to the interface. This has fixed the issue for me.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Your code implements IMyService are you sure that it is XXX.YYY.IMyService.